# Unit Testing VueJS Karma Mocha ExpectJS nextTick not working

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, karma-mocha

I have a simple form with a password field.  If the password input field is empty this span is shown:

```
<span id='password-required' v-show='!validation.password'>Required</span>
```

Once at least one character is entered the `'Required'` message is hidden.  This logic works in the browser just fine.  The problem is that I cannot seem to get the unit test to work.

I figured `nextTick()` would fix it, but it did not. I used code very similar to this for the email field, and it works. I commented out two lines that I also tried, but that also fail. PhantomJS is used.

How do I add a value to the password field and verify that the 'Required' message goes invisible?

```
it(`Hides 'Required' message (password input contains data).`, done => {
  // Extend the component to get the constructor, and initialize directly.
  let email = 'a@b'
  const Constructor = Vue.extend(Login)
  const component = new Constructor({
    propsData: {
      emailentry: email
    }
  }).$mount()

  let password = '123'
  component.$el.querySelector('#password').value = password

  //This line passes.
  expect(component.$el.querySelector('#password').value).to.equal(password)

  // Confirm 'Required' message is hidden.
  Vue.nextTick(() => {
    expect(component.$el.querySelector('#password-required').style.display).to.equal('none')

    // expect(component.validation.password).to.equal(true)
    // expect(!!component.user.password.trim()).to.equal(true)
    done()
  })
})
```

[Login.spec.js Test File](https://github.com/nueverest/vue-signup-login/blob/master/test/unit/specs/Login.spec.js) (Failing tests are commented out.)

[Login.vue Component File](https://github.com/nueverest/vue-signup-login/blob/master/src/components/Login.vue)

Answer (score 0):

I found that the solution is to pass the password data into the component constructor since it is bound like this `<input v-model="password">` to the input tag.

```
let thePassword = '123'

// Extend the component to get the constructor, which we can then initialize directly.
const Constructor = Vue.extend(Signup)
const component = new Constructor({
  propsData: {
    emailentry: email
  },
  data: {
    password: thePassword        
  }
}).$mount()
```

Now the tests are working.